# Setup multiple IP proxy-server

Tags: networking, server, proxy, ip

I am trying to create a simple proxy-server for HTTP(s) traffic(in other words - in order to change IP).

So, i've got 6 ips(from ISP) and VPS with ubuntu 18.04 installed. These ips are linked to a virtual interface, so, i should be able to access these ips from server.

I was trying to make [this][1] solution work, but i failed.

For now im totally out of ideas, was looking towards `squid`, but now looking for any solution for that :)

UPD: did all steps as described in the topic above, but, when trying to get a webpage via proxy -> I don't get any response at all. Just a timeout.

Thought, that it might me problem with some kind of firewall, then disabled iptables at all (ufw is not installed), and made a line `http_access allow all` in squid.cfg file, but, didnt get any response again.

No refused connection, just no response from proxy-server.

UPD2: Now proxy is working, but only for one ip. Seems, that this config

```
http_port 45.153.231.zzz:xxxx name=xxxx
http_port 45.153.231.zzz:xxxx name=xxxx
http_port 45.153.231.zzz:xxxx name=xxxx

acl firstProxy src 188.234.94.xxx
http_access allow all
tcp_outgoing_address 45.153.231.zzz firstProxy

acl secondProxy src 188.234.94.xxx
http_access allow all
tcp_outgoing_address 45.153.231.zzz secondProxy

acl thirdProxy src 188.234.94.xxx
http_access allow all
tcp_outgoing_address 45.153.231.zzz thirdProxy
```

is unable to clarify, which ACL I wanna use now. Any ideas how to make my traffic to be sent via proxy that I need?

For example, by connecting to proxy `45.153.231.zzz` I want all traffic to be sent from this ip to web-server, then the oppsite way to my PC.

Now all traffic is recognized as `firstProxy` ACL, and sent from `45.153.231.zzz`

Comment: Please clarify what did you try and on which step you failed or did not work.

Comment: @KKPatel, updated the topic, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Seems like some process was using port 3030 (which i was trying to connect), and after removing everything(basically just reinstalled whole OS) everything works like a charm.

Here is working cfg

```
http_access allow all

http_port 45.153.231.xxx:zzzz name=zzzz
http_port 45.153.231.xxx:zzzz name=zzzz
http_port 45.153.231.xxx:zzzz name=zzzz

acl 1Proxy myip 45.153.231.xxx
http_access allow all
tcp_outgoing_address 45.153.231.xxx 1Proxy

acl 2Proxy myip 45.153.231.xxx
http_access allow all
tcp_outgoing_address 45.153.231.xxx 2Proxy

acl 3Proxy myip 45.153.231.xxx
http_access allow all
tcp_outgoing_address 45.153.231.xxx 3Proxy
```

But be aware that this confing doesn't declare any auth methods, so that would be absolutely open for everyone.

You have to enable it by using password or IP authentication, depends on you.

But sometimes I'm facing infinite loading pages in browser and Selenium seems not liking that. Think, that it's trouble with squid.